# How to hide a column in a list

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a list linked to a table that whows, let's say, IDs, Names, and Subnames, which are attributes of my table.

For treatment purpose, I want to have the ID on my list, but it is useless for the final users to see its column. So I am looking for a way to hide this column from my list, while keeping the two others (name and subname) visible. And, despite my research, I haven't found a way to do it.

I found the `ColumnHidden` property, but I didn't really understood how it works because I cannot specify one specific column of my list with this (unlike the `Column()` attribute is able to do).

The ideal would be to have something like `Me!List.Column(IDColumn).Visible = False` but obviously it doesn't work.

I hope I am clear enough on what I seek.

Comment: Can be this used: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17254524/hidden-column-in-listbox-access-2007

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just change the width to 0 under the properties in access.  It's a lot easier for me, at least. HTH

Comment: I was about to answer myself. This is the best way to do it as far as I have searched.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide it By resizing it to 0.

```
ListView1.Columns(1).Width = 0
```

then it will be invisible but you can still Access the normal Listview Functions
the Enduser will still be able to resize it and see the content.

that could be prevented by using the ColumnWidthChanging Event:

```
If e.ColumnIndex.Equals(1) Then
        e.NewWidth = 0
        e.Cancel = true
    End If
```

i just tryed that out:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ListView1.Columns(1).Width = 0
    End Sub

    Private Sub ListView1_ColumnWidthChanging(sender As Object, e As ColumnWidthChangingEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ColumnWidthChanging
        If e.ColumnIndex.Equals(1) Then
            e.NewWidth = 0
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

and it worked fine for me.

Comment: What du you call `object sender`? I cannot reproduce because this part is not recognized.